# MongoDB/Mongoose saves and gets wrong integer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a really weird off-by-one error with mongoose - every time I try saving a large number (in this case 76561198063200687) mongoose or mongodb save the integer wrongly.

For example, when I call `SomeModel.findOneAndUpdate({name: "Pietrov"}, {userid: 7656119806320068**7**})`, the field `userid` is being updated to 7656119806320068**8**.

Even weirder is that when I call findOne for the same document **now** (`SomeModel.findOne({name: "Pietrov"})`), the userid is 765611980632006**90** - off by two (of the already wrong, off-by-one userid).

Can someone help me with this bizzare issue?

I'm using mongoose 5.2, although I expereinced the same effect in earlier versions (5.x).

Comment: Can your provide more info ... like mongoose/mongoDB schemas/hooks etc you might have configured?

Comment: Note sure why you closed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836348/race-condition-safety-when-using-async-await-with-database-calls?noredirect=1#comment102103095_57836348) as we could have discussed things further there.  All multi-user databases have features you can use to prevent race conditions.  For example, if you want to add a record for an id if it doesn't already exist, that's a specific operation a database will have an ability to do atomically in one database call.  I don't know your specific database so you'll have to do some research on that topic.

Comment: And, it is even worse with clustering because that creates more opportunities for race conditions (more servers all competing to modify the same database).

Comment: Sorry, I've undeleted the post now! Feel free to post your comments again in there. Also great points. I'm using postgres and haven't yet found a way to do exactly what I want in a single query. I'm tempted to (mis-) use transactions for this but fear that that's an awful way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is not related to mongodb or mongoose. This seemingly weird behavior caused by the fact that your number is not a **safe integer**:

```
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER < 76561198063200688 // true
Number.isSafeInteger(76561198063200688)     // false
```

All numbers in JavaScript are double-precision floating-point format numbers. And this numbers can safely represent only integers between `-(2**53 - 1)` and `2**53 - 1`. It means that if you are using integers outside of that range, they can be rounded to fit the IEEE-754 representation. Look at [isSafeInteger documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) for more information.

JavaScript now has a new type for arbitrary-precision integers called [BigInt](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint). But they are only supported in node [starting from version 10.4](https://node.green/#ESNEXT-candidate--stage-3--BigInt). And as far as I understand mongoose doesn't work with big integers by default, so you may need to create a [custom schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html) for them. Otherwise, store this ids as strings, because you probably don't need to perform any computations with them.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Do you think it would be "bad database design" to store these numbers in strings? After all, you should store integers as integers - at least from what I've heard

Comment: It really depends on what this field represents. If it is used only as an unique identifier, then I think it doesn't matter. Only downside that I can think of is that string representation will take a bit more space. On the other hand, if you need to increment them, compare numerically, or query records from certain range of values, then using strings would be a really bad idea.

Comment: There is still the way to convert string numbers during a query into BigInt or anything like that if you have to work with calculations and then convert it back into a `String` again before updating the DB.